# After object rotation the object scale doesn't work right: UWP

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core, uwp, uwp-xaml

I have a problem which I can't figure out how to solve. I have a user control scale and rotate.
The scale works fine, but when I rotate the object the scale doesn't work right it.
[image]

[image]

Here is the XAML

```
    <Border Name="rectangle1" Background="Blue"
         Width="200" Height="200" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5">
        <Border.RenderTransform>
            <RotateTransform x:Name="image_rotate"/>
        </Border.RenderTransform>  
    </Border>
</Canvas>
```

And here is the C#

```
public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private enum HitType
    {
        None, Body, UL, UR, LR, LL, L, R, T, B
    };

    // True if a drag is in progress.
    private bool DragInProgress = false;

    // The drag's last point.
    private Point LastPoint;

    // The part of the rectangle under the mouse.
    HitType MouseHitType = HitType.None;
    private bool isRotate = false;

    // Return a HitType value to indicate what is at the point.
    private HitType SetHitType(Border rect, Point point)
    {
        double left = Canvas.GetLeft(rect);
        double top = Canvas.GetTop(rect);
        double right = left + rect.Width;
        double bottom = top + rect.Height;
        if (point.X < left) return HitType.None;
        if (point.X > right) return HitType.None;
        if (point.Y < top) return HitType.None;
        if (point.Y > bottom) return HitType.None;

        const double GAP = 10;
        if (point.X - left < GAP)
        {
            // Left edge.
            if (point.Y - top < GAP) return HitType.UL;
            if (bottom - point.Y < GAP) return HitType.LL;
            return HitType.L;
        }
        if (right - point.X < GAP)
        {
            // Right edge.
            if (point.Y - top < GAP) return HitType.UR;
            if (bottom - point.Y < GAP) return HitType.LR;
            return HitType.R;
        }
        if (point.Y - top < GAP) return HitType.T;
        if (bottom - point.Y < GAP) return HitType.B;
        return HitType.Body;
    }

    // Set a mouse cursor appropriate for the current hit type.
    private void SetMouseCursor()
    {
        // See what cursor we should display.
        Window.Current.CoreWindow.PointerCursor = new Windows.UI.Core.CoreCursor(Windows.UI.Core.CoreCursorType.Arrow, 0);
        switch (MouseHitType)
        {
            case HitType.None:
                Window.Current.CoreWindow.PointerCursor = new Windows.UI.Core.CoreCursor(Windows.UI.Core.CoreCursorType.Arrow, 0);
                break;
            case HitType.Body:
                Window.Current.CoreWindow.PointerCursor = new Windows.UI.Core.CoreCursor(Windows.UI.Core.CoreCursorType.Hand, 0);
                break;
            case HitType.UL:
            case HitType.LR:
                Window.Current.CoreWindow.PointerCursor = new Windows.UI.Core.CoreCursor(Windows.UI.Core.CoreCursorType.SizeNorthwestSoutheast, 0);
                break;
            case HitType.LL:
            case HitType.UR:
                Window.Current.CoreWindow.PointerCursor = new Windows.UI.Core.CoreCursor(Windows.UI.Core.CoreCursorType.SizeNortheastSouthwest, 0);
                break;
            case HitType.T:
            case HitType.B:
                Window.Current.CoreWindow.PointerCursor = new Windows.UI.Core.CoreCursor(Windows.UI.Core.CoreCursorType.SizeNorthSouth, 0);
                break;
            case HitType.L:
            case HitType.R:
                Window.Current.CoreWindow.PointerCursor = new Windows.UI.Core.CoreCursor(Windows.UI.Core.CoreCursorType.SizeWestEast, 0);
                break;
        }
    }

    // Start dragging.
    private void canvas1_MouseDown(object sender, PointerRoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        isRotate = false;
        var position = e.GetCurrentPoint(canvas1);
        MouseHitType = SetHitType(rectangle1, position.Position);
        SetMouseCursor();
        DragInProgress = true;
        if (MouseHitType == HitType.None)
        {
            //var Pos = e.GetCurrentPoint(canvas1);   
            //double dx = Pos.Position.X - ImageCenter.X;
            //double dy = Pos.Position.Y - ImageCenter.Y;
            isRotate = true;
            //StartAngle = (float)Math.Atan2(dy, dx);
            //return;

        }
        var lastPos = e.GetCurrentPoint(canvas1);
        LastPoint = lastPos.Position;

    }



    // If a drag is in progress, continue the drag.
    // Otherwise display the correct cursor.
    private void canvas1_MouseMove(object sender, PointerRoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        var position = e.GetCurrentPoint(canvas1);
        if (!DragInProgress)
        {
            MouseHitType = SetHitType(rectangle1, position.Position);
            SetMouseCursor();

        }
        else
        {
            // See how much the mouse has moved.
            Point point = position.Position;
            double offset_x = point.X - LastPoint.X;
            double offset_y = point.Y - LastPoint.Y;

            // Get the rectangle's current position.
            double new_x = Canvas.GetLeft(rectangle1);
            double new_y = Canvas.GetTop(rectangle1);
            double new_width = rectangle1.Width;
            double new_height = rectangle1.Height;

            // Update the rectangle.
            switch (MouseHitType)
            {
                case HitType.Body:
                    new_x += offset_x;
                    new_y += offset_y;
                    break;
                case HitType.UL:
                    new_x += offset_x;
                    new_y += offset_y;
                    new_width -= offset_x;
                    new_height -= offset_y;
                    break;
                case HitType.UR:
                    new_y += offset_y;
                    new_width += offset_x;
                    new_height -= offset_y;
                    break;
                case HitType.LR:
                    new_width += offset_x;
                    new_height += offset_y;
                    break;
                case HitType.LL:
                    new_x += offset_x;
                    new_width -= offset_x;
                    new_height += offset_y;
                    break;
                case HitType.L:
                    new_x += offset_x;
                    new_width -= offset_x;
                    break;
                case HitType.R:
                    new_width += offset_x;
                    break;
                case HitType.B:
                    new_height += offset_y;
                    break;
                case HitType.T:
                    new_y += offset_y;
                    new_height -= offset_y;
                    break;
            }

            // Don't use negative width or height.
            if ((new_width > 0) && (new_height > 0))
            {
                // Update the rectangle.
                Canvas.SetLeft(rectangle1, new_x);
                Canvas.SetTop(rectangle1, new_y);
                rectangle1.Width = new_width;
                rectangle1.Height = new_height;

                // Save the mouse's new location.
                LastPoint = point;
            }
        }
    }

    // Stop dragging.
    private void canvas1_MouseUp(object sender, PointerRoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        isRotate = false;
        DragInProgress = false;
    }

    private void canvas1_ManipulationDelta(object sender, ManipulationDeltaRoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (isRotate)
        {
            image_rotate.Angle += e.Delta.Translation.X;
        }
    }
}
```

As shown in the pictures when the object has not rotated the cursor is on the right position for scaling, but when I rotate the object the cursor position for the scaling is not changed and it scales from two sides.
Please let me know if you have a suggestion.
Thanks!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is the transformation origin.

When you rotate, the center of the rectangle has changed, as shown below:

[image: Imgur]

**Update**

When performing `RenderTransform`, the effect on the element is only visual. Does not affect the actual position of the element.

In the case of rotate, your `SetHitType` method cannot determine the skewed edges.

Calculating the hypotenuse is very difficult, my suggestion is that you can add 9 auxiliary points like this:

[image: Imgur]

The change is triggered only when the Pointer moves to the corresponding point, which can simplify the problem we encounter.

Best regards.

Comment: Thanks for your response. But now the problem is even deeper. After scaling the mouse points won't be in the right position too.

Comment: Hi, I'm sorry, the previous answer may be misleading, and I have modified the answer now. It is also recommended that you use handles instead of calculating boundaries. Beveled edges become difficult to calculate when tilted

Comment: Thanks for your response. The answer really helped. If you can please send me any link that can help me doing it.

Comment: Hi, there is currently no documentation on this handles, this is not an official control. But there are some similar controls in the community to refer to, this [ImageCropper](https://github.com/windows-toolkit/WindowsCommunityToolkit/tree/master/Microsoft.Toolkit.Uwp.UI.Controls/ImageCropper) from `WindowsCommunityToolkit`, maybe it can provide a good template